# Получение изображения из формы

Tags: python, django

Делаю сайт, который должен преобразовывать изображение при помощи стороннего скрипта, но **не могу получить и сохранить изображение от пользователя**

Код:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import DB_Form
from .models import DB_Image
#import pic_script

def index(request):
    images = DB_Image.objects.all()
    form = DB_Form()
    return render(request, "index.html", context = {'form' : form})

def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        img = DB_Image()
        img.image = request.POST.get("img_form")
        img.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from firstapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('create/', views.create),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class DB_Form(forms.Form):
    img_form = forms.ImageField(label = "")
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class DB_Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="create/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>{{ form }}</p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Обработать" ></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если используешь `form` то тебе нужно самостоятельно сделать сохранение этого изображения на диск для постоянного хранения, а так же в модель.
Используй `ModelForm` она за тебя автоматически переместит сохраненное изображение в ту папку, которая указана по `upload_to="images"` и сохранит модель в БД

```
class DB_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    Meta:
        model = DB_Image
        field = ("image",)
```

соответственно, после того, как ты сохранишь форму изображение у тебя будет находится в папке на диске и преобразовывай его как тебе нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ Андрея, безусловно, очень мне помог, но не решил проблему полностью, как оказалось, я допустил ошибку в файле **index.html**, прикладываю исправления:

```
<form method="POST"  action = "create/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

А также пришлось подвергнуть существенным изменениям файл **views.py**:

```
def index(request):
    images = DB_Image.objects.all()
    form = DB_Form(request.POST, request.FILES)
    return render(request, "index.html", context = {'form' : form})

def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        img = DB_Image()
        form = DB_Form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        img.image = request.POST.get("img_form")
        img.save()
        form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```